# Does std::map auto balance itself

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, containers

I know that mainstream implementations of STL map/set use black-red trees.
My question is: do these implementations also auto-balance the tree when inserting/deleting elements?

If not, then when the elements are sorted and inserted, it will always append to the rightmost place. The worst lookup cost is O(n).

So, does the black-red tree auto-balance itself?

Comment: From wikipedia: *A red–black tree is a kind of **self-balancing** binary search tree.*

Comment: IMHO, `::std::map` should use a B-Tree with tree-nodes calibrated to a small multiple of the page size. Locality of reference on the page level gets to be one of the biggest performance concerns with truly large trees. But, yes, red-black trees are self-balancing by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) and [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) *std::map* operations.

It is guaranteed that the worst complexity for these operations is logarithmic.

In fact it is not important which type of a tree is used to implement an *std::map*. But this tree must provide necessary complexity for *insert*, *erase* and some other operations. Basically it means that the tree must be balanced (and, of course, auto-balance itself when elements are inserted into or removed from).

The same is true for an *std::set*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Red-black trees perform node rotations to ensure that the tree remains balanced

Answer (score 1):

Yes. in Red-Black trees after each insertion, some of elements in the tree will be moved to new place if the tree is not balanced.