# Best C++ STL way to map ranges to values?

Tags: c++

Want to know the most efficient way to map ranges of values in C++

When for example:

I have a bunch of objects differentiated by integer key ranges, e.g.

```
0-10 -> object a
11-20 -> object b
21-30 -> object c
```

Where objects are a particular class with a few variables of their own inside. There should be a thousand objects in this scenario.

**I was wondering what is the best/fastest way in C++ STL to lookup an object based on an input key. e.g.**

```
lookup(13) -> object b
```

Note that the ranges are not fixed and may not be of equal size.

Thanks

Comment: Are the ranges of equal (or otherwise easily computable) sizes, or is that an artifact of the example?

Comment: Are the ranges fixed? If you have a value `i`, can you by simple arithmetic know exactly which range it will be in? For example with the value `13`, if you do `13 / 10 * 10 + 1` you will get `11`, and from that know the start of the range which will be `11` to `20`.

Comment: And if the start of the range can be easily calculated, then why not simply an `std::unordered_map` that maps the beginning of the range to the object? So e.g. `range_to_object_map[i / 10 * 10 + 1]` will be the object you're looking for. Perhaps with a special case for `0` since that's the only entry not following the pattern of the rest.

Comment: I am really wondering, why the answer below has been deleted. Technically it is a good answer

Comment: Check out [Boost.ICL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html), if you're not constrained to STL.

Comment: @AM You mean the one that read like a [ChatGPT](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) response?

Comment: @DavisHerring no ranges are not of equal size.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ranges are not fixed either, so cant calculate

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do not know nor use chatgpt

Comment: @AM I don't claim that you use or have used it, but that now deleted answer have a very ChatGPT-ish feeling about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily accomplished with std::map and it's upper_bound function.

Use the lower end of each range as the key into a map. The corresponding value of the map type is a triple of `{lower bound, upper bound, and item}`.  Then to lookup an object based on a specific value, invoke map::upper_bound and to find the the item in the map that is "one past" the matching item. Then "go back 1" and test to see if it's a match.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct RangeAndValue
{
    int low;
    int high;
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
struct RangeTable
{
    std::map<int, RangeAndValue<T>> table;
    void Insert(int low, int high, const T& t)
    {
        table[low] = {low, high, t};
    }

    bool Lookup(int value, T& t)
    {
        auto itor = table.upper_bound(value);
        if (itor != table.begin())
        {
            itor--;
            if ((value >= itor->second.low) && (value <= itor->second.high))
            {
                t = itor->second.value;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Proof of concept (using your sample ranges of `0-10` maps to a, `11-20` maps to b, and `21-30` maps to c)

```
int main()
{
    RangeTable<std::string> rangeTable;

    rangeTable.Insert(0, 10, "a");
    rangeTable.Insert(11,20, "b");
    rangeTable.Insert(21,30, "c");

    for (int i = -1; i < 32; i++)
    {
        std::string s;
        bool result = rangeTable.Lookup(i, s);
        std::cout << i << " : " << (result ? s : "<not found>") << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces expected results when run:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o testapp
$ ./testapp
-1 : <not found>
0 : a
1 : a
2 : a
3 : a
4 : a
5 : a
6 : a
7 : a
8 : a
9 : a
10 : a
11 : b
12 : b
13 : b
14 : b
15 : b
16 : b
17 : b
18 : b
19 : b
20 : b
21 : c
22 : c
23 : c
24 : c
25 : c
26 : c
27 : c
28 : c
29 : c
30 : c
31 : <not found>
```

Comment: Thanks. Isnt this O(n) complexity for lookup worst case? Is a O(log n) solution possible?

Comment: It should be O(lg n) in the worse case too. Look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound#Complexity) and [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/upper_bound/#complexity) for the sections on complexity.  Unlike the methods in std::unordered_map, the lookup methods in std::map don't say anything about a worse case. The whole point of std::map is that it maintains ordering. So  I would imagine upper_bound is an O(lg n) search to the bottom of the tree and then a few O(1) steps to find the previous node. I'm assuming std::map is binary tree and linked list combo.

Comment: Aha... std::map is a red-black tree that self balances.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312329/does-stdmap-auto-balance-itself) . That's how it can assert O(lg n) in worse case.

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as @selbie's answer, but using a [transparent comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/2752075) to avoid wrapping the map in your own class:

```
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct Range
{
    T begin{}, end{};

    friend constexpr auto operator<=>(const Range &, const Range &) = default;
    friend constexpr std::weak_ordering operator<=>(const Range &a, T b)
    {
        if (b < a.begin)
            return std::weak_ordering::greater;
        else if (b > a.end)
            return std::weak_ordering::less;
        else
            return std::weak_ordering::equivalent;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<Range<int>, std::string, std::less<>> m = {
        {{0, 5}, "A"},
        {{6, 10}, "B"},
        {{11, 15}, "C"},
    };

    auto check = [&](int n)
    {
        auto it = m.find(n);
        if (it != m.end())
            std::cout << n << " -> " << it->second << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << n << " not in the map\n";
    };

    check(0); // A
    check(1); // A
    check(5); // A
    check(6); // B
    check(-1); // not in the map
    check(16); // not in the map
}
```

First, we use `std::less<>` (without the template argument - the transparent version), which makes `.find()` a template, accepting any type comparable with the key type.

Next we make a range class that overloads comparison operators (using C++20) with itself and with its element type.

You could do the same thing with `std::pair` and with a custom transparent comparator (add `using is_transparent = void;`) that compares it with the numbers in the correct way.